# Python 1-100 multiply numbers with functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def main():
    for sayi in range(1,100):
        if not sayi%2==0:
            sonuc=hesapla(sayi)
            print(sonuc)

def hesapla(sayi):
    carpim = 1
    if carpim == 1:
        carpim=carpim*sayi
        return carpim
main()
```

It's not working, I want to print:

```
1
3
15
105
945
10395
135135
2027025
34459425
654729075
13749310575
316234143225
.................
```

But it's printing:

```
1
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
21
...............
```

Comment: Seems like a homework... :)

Comment: Sssh be cool :)

Comment: "_It's not working_" is not a question. Ask a clear question regarding your code that we can answer and help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in only one function. See below.

```
def main():
    sonuc = 1
    for sayi in range(1,100):
        if not sayi%2==0:
            sonuc=sonuc*sayi
            print(sonuc)
main()
```

A two function way of doing this is below:

```
def main():
    sonuc=1
    for sayi in range(1,100):
        if not sayi%2==0:
            sonuc=hesapla(sonuc,sayi)
            print(sonuc)

def hesapla(sonuc,sayi):
   carpim=sonuc*sayi
   return carpim

main()
```

*EDIT* Below is a simplified method using steps as opposed to using i%2 check:

```
def main():
    sonuc=1
    for sayi in range(1,100,2):
        sonuc=hesapla(sonuc,sayi)
        print(sonuc)

def hesapla(sonuc,sayi):
   return sonuc*sayi

main()
```

Comment: No I want to use two function (main and hesapla(in English: calculate) )

Comment: Why do you want to use two functions?

Comment: Because my practice book want to two function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a running product instead of recalculating it each time.

```
x = 1
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
    x *= i
    print(x)
```

EDIT:

You really don't need two functions to do this.  It's a waste of resources and unnecessarily complex.  I'll assume that someone is making you do this

```
def main():
    for i in range(1, 100, 2):
        print(calculate(i))

def calculate(i):
    x = 1
    for n in range(1, i+1, 2):
        x *= n
    return x
```

Comment: Yes I know but my practice book want to two function. Thanks.